# Merge 3 queries into a single sub query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is it possible to write a single query to fetch data from the 3 tables?
Below are the 3 queries that I am running to fetch data, but would need a single query.

I have tried to write the below query but the data I amgetting is wrong

```
(SELECT M_NB,M_GF_IND,M_HEDGE_LNK  FROM TABLE#DATA#DEALCOM_DBF  WHERE  M_GF_IND = 'Y' ) A
(SELECT M_NB,M_GF_IND,M_HEDGE_LNK  FROM TABLE#DATA#DEALIRD_DBF  WHERE  M_GF_IND = 'Y' ) B
(SELECT M_NB,M_GF_IND,M_HEDGE_LNK  FROM TABLE#DATA#DEALSCF_DBF  WHERE  M_GF_IND = 'Y' ) C
```

I have tried to write the below query but the data I am getting is wrong

```
SELECT DD.M_NB, DD.M_GF_IND, DD.M_HEDGE_LNK,
       FF.M_NB, FF.M_GF_IND, FF.M_HEDGE_LNK 
FROM TABLE#DATA#DEALCOM_DBF DD,
     TABLE#DATA#DEALIRD_DBF FF  
WHERE  DD.M_GF_IND = 'Y' and FF.M_GF_IND = 'Y'
```

Sorry if this is a bad question,  I am new to SQL and thus cannot figure out. Will update if I find any alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for `UNION` (`ALL`)?

```
SELECT M_NB,M_GF_IND,M_HEDGE_LNK  FROM TABLE#DATA#DEALCOM_DBF  WHERE  M_GF_IND = 'Y' 
UNION ALL
SELECT M_NB,M_GF_IND,M_HEDGE_LNK  FROM TABLE#DATA#DEALIRD_DBF  WHERE  M_GF_IND = 'Y' 
UNION ALL
SELECT M_NB,M_GF_IND,M_HEDGE_LNK  FROM TABLE#DATA#DEALSCF_DBF  WHERE  M_GF_IND = 'Y';
```

Comment: No problem, I'm glad if it helped.